# DotNetNuke 404 custom page not working

Tags: dotnetnuke-7

I created a new page, and set permissions to all users. On site settings set it as 404 page, but still get the system page for 404 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only works if Friendly Url Provider mode is set 'advanced' on web.config:

```
<friendlyUrl defaultProvider="DNNFriendlyUrl">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="DNNFriendlyUrl" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Url.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider, DotNetNuke.HttpModules" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^a-zA-Z0-9 _-]" urlFormat="advanced" />
  </providers>
</friendlyUrl>
```

Urls will be changed. Spaces will be replaced by "-" and aspx extension is removed.